# Problems with Python factorial results

Tags: python, math, factorial

I am not sure whether this is related to `math.factorial` function or it is related to some typecasting or whatever. This is what I know:

```
>>> factorial(52)/ (factorial(52-48) - factorial(48))
-6497401L
```

So, with that code I am trying to calculate the number of possible combinations of a set of 52 different elements taken in groups of 48. And the result I am getting is a negative number, that makes no sense at all.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: `factorial(52-48)` means  `factorial(4)`. If you subtract `factorial(48)` from this you will get a negative number.

Comment: You are getting a negative number because `factorial(52-48)` is the same as `factorial(4)` which is negative when you subtract `factorial(48)` from it.  With a positive numerator and a negative denominator, you're bound to get a negative result.

Comment: Ah, I see. I committed a typo and put a - where I should have put an *.

Comment: Can I remove this question somehow?

Comment: @Fran You can delete your own question

Comment: FWIW, it's generally not very efficient to use factorials to calculate binomial coefficients. Eg, your example can be reduced to 4 multiplications and 4 (integer) divisions. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26561091/4014959) for further info.

Comment: @Selcuk It seems I can't because it has answers. I have requested a moderator intervention to do so. I hope they do it.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using this code precisely to test another algorithm that makes the same calculations in a different way within a unittest, so I need it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Your math is wrong. It should be `N!/(S! * (S - N)!)` - you are subtracting instead of multiplying in the denominator:

```
>>> factorial(52) / (factorial(52-48) * factorial(48))
270725L
```

Comment: The OP would like to delete this Q because it's just a typo.