# How to obtain the nth row of the pascal triangle

Tags: python

Here is my code to find the nth row of pascals triangle

```
def pascaline(n):
     line = [1]       
     for k in range(max(n,0)):             
         line.append(line[k]*(n-k)/(k+1))             
     return line
```

There are two things I would like to ask. First, the outputs integers end with .0 always like in

```
pascaline(2) = [1, 2.0, 1.0]
```

How do I remove those .0 at the end? also, how can I do to start at $n=1$ and not at $0$? For instance, in this case, pascaline(2) should be [1, 1] and not [1, 2, 1]

Comment: Why do you want `pascaline(2)` to be `[1, 1]` ? Under the usual definition it _should_ be `[1, 2, 1]`. I'm also curious as to why you do `max(n,0)`; I'd be inclined to raise `ValueError` if the function is called with a negative argument. FWIW, you may be interested in the 2nd version of the `binomial(n, r)` function in [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26561091/4014959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subtract 1 from n and typecast. basically change your method to this:

```
def pascaline(n):
    n = n - 1
    line = [1]

    for k in range(max(n ,0)):

        line.append(int(line[k]*(n-k)/(k+1)))

    return line
print(pascaline(5));
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's more elegant (& more efficient) to simply use  `//` floor division rather than float division and converting the float to an integer.

Answer (score 8):

the .0 can be removed by taking the floor division using `//` instead of float division with `/` so your code would be `line.append(line[k]*(n-k)//(k+1))`. To get it to start one back just make n one less with `n -= 1`.

```
def pascaline(n):
     n -= 1
     line = [1]
     for k in range(max(n,0)):             
         line.append(line[k]*(n-k)//(k+1))             
     return line


pascaline(2) >>> [1,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've got your answer. The problem is you are dealing with floating point numbers, *not* integers. This is programming, not math. Numbers are represented concretely. I just wanted to compare these two implementations, where the first one let's you save some calculation time by using symmetry. Both are still O(n), though:

```
def pascal_line(n):
    line = [1]
    mid, even = divmod(n, 2)
    for k in range(1, mid + 1):
        num = int(line[k-1]*(n + 1 - k)/(k))
        line.append(num)
    reverse_it = reversed(line)
    if not even:
        next(reverse_it)
    for n in reverse_it:
        line.append(n)
    return line

def pascal_line2(n):
    line = [1]
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        num = int(line[k-1]*(n + 1 - k)/(k))
        line.append(num)
    return line
```

Now, in action:

```
>>> for i in range(21):
...   print(pascal_line(i))
... 
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
[1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1]
[1, 11, 55, 165, 330, 462, 462, 330, 165, 55, 11, 1]
[1, 12, 66, 220, 495, 792, 924, 792, 495, 220, 66, 12, 1]
[1, 13, 78, 286, 715, 1287, 1716, 1716, 1287, 715, 286, 78, 13, 1]
[1, 14, 91, 364, 1001, 2002, 3003, 3432, 3003, 2002, 1001, 364, 91, 14, 1]
[1, 15, 105, 455, 1365, 3003, 5005, 6435, 6435, 5005, 3003, 1365, 455, 105, 15, 1]
[1, 16, 120, 560, 1820, 4368, 8008, 11440, 12870, 11440, 8008, 4368, 1820, 560, 120, 16, 1]
[1, 17, 136, 680, 2380, 6188, 12376, 19448, 24310, 24310, 19448, 12376, 6188, 2380, 680, 136, 17, 1]
[1, 18, 153, 816, 3060, 8568, 18564, 31824, 43758, 48620, 43758, 31824, 18564, 8568, 3060, 816, 153, 18, 1]
[1, 19, 171, 969, 3876, 11628, 27132, 50388, 75582, 92378, 92378, 75582, 50388, 27132, 11628, 3876, 969, 171, 19, 1]
[1, 20, 190, 1140, 4845, 15504, 38760, 77520, 125970, 167960, 184756, 167960, 125970, 77520, 38760, 15504, 4845, 1140, 190, 20, 1]
```

Now, a quick and dirty time-test:

```
>>> def time_me(f, n):
...   start = time.time()
...   f(n)
...   stop = time.time()
... 
>>> times = [time_me(pascal_line,n) for n in range(10, 1001,10)]
>>> times2 = [time_me(pascal_line2,n) for n in range(10, 1001,10)]
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> n = range(10, 1001,10)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'pascal_lines':times, 'pascal_lines2':times2},index=list(n))
>>> df.plot()
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f6c1c3d1c18>
>>> plt.savefig('pascal.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Not sure if it is worth it, since I'm reaching an `OverFlow` error somewhere soon after n = 1000.

### EDIT

As others have pointed out, using integer division instead of converting from float to int is more efficient. It also has the added benefit of not throwing: `OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float` after around n = 1000.

```
def pascal_line0(n):
    line = [1]
    mid, even = divmod(n, 2)
    for k in range(1, mid + 1):
        num = line[k-1]*(n + 1 - k)//(k)
        line.append(num)
    reverse_it = reversed(line)
    if not even:
        next(reverse_it)
    for n in reverse_it:
        line.append(n)
    return line
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe test the speed of doing the reversing via extended slicing? Eg, `return line + line[even-2::-1]`

Comment: @PM2Ring Hmm, my gut says it would not be faster since slicing builds a new list from scratch. Especially if you use +, which then goes on to build yet another list. At least something like `line += line[even = 2::-1]; return line`.

Comment: True, slicing does build a new list from scratch, but it's pretty fast, since it does it in C code. And instead of `+` concatenation, we could do `line.extend(line[even-2::-1]); return line`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, `+=` is essentially equivalent to `list.extend`. Also, list's `__reversed__` method is likely implemented in C as well. I would be interested in finding out... Anyway, if you want to test the two, be my guest.

Comment: On the topic of speed, `divmod` is convenient, but calling a Python function tends to be slower than using operators; in my tests `q, r = divmod(a, b)` is a little slower than `q, r = a // b, a % b`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sure, you could probably squeeze more performance by tweaking lots of things. If you were to go down that route, we could start by "in-lining" `list.append` to remove the overhead of method-lookup:`line_append = line.append`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Also, `divmod` is used once in the code, so the savings are mostly inconsequential.