# Divisions between large numbers with long integers: how to bypass float conversion?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, long-integer, largenumber

I need to calculate a ratio between very large numbers as shown in the code:

```
import scipy.special

x=2000
n=range(8,x+1)
q=[]

for i in range(0,len(n)):

    q.append(((n[i]-6)*26**(n[i]-7)-scipy.special.binom(n[i]//7+n[i]%7,n[i]//7))*(26**n[i])**(-1))
```

I get errors since numbers are too large:

```
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

how can I handle such large numbers?

Comment: maybe you could drop `scipy` binomial coefficient in favor of custom implementation like found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560726/python-binomial-coefficient. Seems to use integers.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem seems not to be in the binomial coefficient, but in the powers of 26

Comment: so maybe you could create a [mcve] not using `scipy`. You may get more answers that way.

Comment: @user4288514 the `**` operator should return an `int` if it is working with two `int` objects.

Comment: which version of python do you use?

Comment: I am using python 2.7, Paul Panzer's answer works well with python3 btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scipy.special.comb` with the `exact` kwd and replace *large^(-1) with /large:

```
import scipy.special

x=2000
n=range(8,x+1)
q=[]

for i in range(0,len(n)):

    q.append(((n[i]-6)*26**(n[i]-7)-scipy.special.comb(n[i]//7+n[i]%7,n[i]//7, exact=True))/(26**n[i]))

print(q[-10:])

# [2.4714229501232675e-07, 2.4726679994684175e-07, 2.473913048813568e-07, 2.4751580981587185e-07, 2.4764031475038685e-07, 2.477648196849019e-07, 2.478893246194169e-07, 2.4801382955393194e-07, 2.4813833448844694e-07, 2.48262839422962e-07]
```

Division itself doesn't seem to be a problem:

```
(3**100)/(4**88)
# 5.380792381981753e-06
```

Note: The above appplies to Python3. On Python2 division between ints defaults to return an int. You can either use `__truediv__`

```
    q.append(((n[i]-6)*26**(n[i]-7)-scipy.special.comb(n[i]//7+n[i]%7,n[i]//7, exact=True)).__truediv__((26**n[i])))
```

or use a future import

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: If speed matters, it may also be worth investigating using a simple-minded combinations implementation based on `math.factorial` in place of `scipy.special.comb`.

Comment: Ok, this same exact code works if I use python3 since it doesn't need to convert numbers to float to make division (am I right?). There is a way using python 2.7 as well?

Comment: @user4288514 Yep, on Python2 you  can use `int1.__truediv__(int2)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The problem with using factorial is that you are doing quite a few (>~ n)superfluous multiplications

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Yep, but it's done in optimised C instead of Python. It wouldn't surprise me to find out that it's faster in spite of the extra multiplications.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: A somewhat random test at the IPython prompt gives me timings of ~12us for `scipy.special.comb(250, 73, exact=True)` versus ~8.7us for a simple `math.factorial(250) / math.factorial(73) / math.factorial(177)`. So not a huge difference, but a significant one. Your results may vary.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Who'd have thought? Btw. if you have `sympy`, it has a `FallingFactorial` which  is even faster in your test case (2x on my machine). But obviously, it also has `binomial` which gives another (5x) speedup.