# Evaluating algebraic expressions with combinations

Tags: python, math, algebra

I need help with evaluating the expression. I just started it but at a loss for what next plus all the for loops I am using seem unnecessary. it has sum, products and combinations:

[image: a complicated mathematical equations]

What I tried is incomplete and in my opinion not accurate. I tried several but all I can come up with for now. I don't have the denominator yet.

```
i = 10
N = 3.1
j = []
for x in range(1, i + 1):
    for y in range(1, i):
        for z in range(1, n - i):            
            l = N * y * z
            j.append(l)
            ll = sum(j)
```

Any help is appreciated. I want to be able to understand it so I can do more complex examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints. If you try them and are still stuck, ask for more help.

First, you know that the expression involves "combinations," also called "binomial coefficients." So you will need a routine that calculates those. [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560726/python-binomial-coefficient) with multiple answers on how to calculate these numbers. Briefly, you can use the `scipy` package or make your own routine that uses Python's `factorial` function or that uses iteration.

Next, you see that the expression involves sums and products and is written as a single expression. Python has a `sum` function which works on generator expressions (as well as list and set generators and other iterables). Your conversion from math to Python will be easier if you know how to set up such expressions. If you do not understand these generators/iterables and how to sum them, do research on this topic. This approach is not necessary, since you could use loops rather than the generators, but this approach will be easier. Study until you can understand an expression (including why the final number in the `range` has `1` added to it) such as

```
sum(N * f(x) for x in range(1, 5+1))
```

Last, your expression has products, but Python has no built-in way to take the product of an iterable. Here is such a function in Python 3.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def prod(iterable):
    """Return the product of the numbers in an iterable."""
    return reduce(mul, iterable, 1)
```

With all of that, your desired expression will look like this (you will need to finish the job by replacing the `...` with something more useful):

```
numerator = sum(N * prod(... for y in range(1, 1+1)) for x in range(1, 5+1))
denominator = prod(y + N for y in range(1, 5+1))
result = numerator / denominator
```

Note that your final result is a function of `N`.

Comment: I was not sure of the product expression. This makes it much clearer now. I have a lot more to solve so I will give it a run plus research more on the generator method. Thank you for the concise explanation

Comment: You are welcome. On this site, show your appreciation by accepting the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Comment: I did try to do that but it was just recorded and not shown publicly. I guess it is because I just joined (newbie)