# Interpreting a recursive function that produces a list of palindromes

Tags: python, recursion

I recently encountered the below functions. When trying to interpret it, I originally got lost trying to understand how the first function, with both inputs, could be added to one another until it seems that "y" becomes either equal to 0 or "x". Furthermore, what I found odd is that I don't need to define any variables for "x" or "y" but simply pass a number "N" through the second function and a "palindrome" list is produced such as [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1] in the case of passing N=7. Could someone help me understand the relationship of the first function with its recursive function and how the relationship to the second function produces the list of numbers? I.e. what kind of algorithm is this?

```
def func(x, y):
  if y in (0, x):
    return 1
  return func(x-1, y-1) + func(x-1, y)



def func2(N):
  return [[func(x, y) for y in range(x + 1)] for x in range(N)][N-1]
```

Comment: This is an (extremely inefficient) implementation of the logic behind [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: Note that if `y > x`, this function recurses infinitely and blows your stack.

Answer (score 2):

As @user2357112 noted, it's related to [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) which in turn related to [binomial expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).  The values returned by `func2(N)` are the coefficients of the expansion of `(x+y)^(N-1)`.

For example, `(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2` so `func2(3)` returns `[1, 2, 1]`

The other function, `func(x,y)` is simply recursively walking up Pascal's triangle in order to determine the appropriate value for that term.  Note from the link that each term in Pascal's triangle is the sum of the 2 terms directly above it.  Your code traverses the triangle once for each term in the bottom level which makes it much less efficient than other ways of calculating binomial expansion coefficients.

You can also calculate the binomial coefficients directly:

The coefficient of `x^(n−k)*y^k` is given by the formula `n!/(k!(n-k)!)` an efficient implementation of which is provided by [scipy.misc.comb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html)

Answer (score 2):

I instrumented your inner function to trace the operations in painstaking detail.  Each recursion is indented an extra 2 spaces; each `print` has a label, the original `x, y` values, and any extra information recently computed.

```
indent = ""
def func(x, y):
  global indent
  print(indent, "ENTER", x, y)
  indent += "  "    # increase output indentation

  if y in (0, x):
    result = 1
  else:
    part1 = func(x-1, y-1)
    print(indent, "PART1", x, y, part1)
    part2 = func(x-1, y)
    print(indent, "PART2", x, y, part2)

    result = part1 + part2

  indent = indent[2:]   # decrease output indentation
  print(indent, "LEAVE", x, y, result)
  return result


def func2(N):
  return [[func(x, y) for y in range(x + 1)] for x in range(N)][N-1]


print(func2(5))
```

Output:

```
 ENTER 0 0
 LEAVE 0 0 1
 ENTER 1 0
 LEAVE 1 0 1
 ENTER 1 1
 LEAVE 1 1 1
 ENTER 2 0
 LEAVE 2 0 1
 ENTER 2 1
   ENTER 1 0
   LEAVE 1 0 1
   PART1 2 1 1
   ENTER 1 1
   LEAVE 1 1 1
   PART2 2 1 1
 LEAVE 2 1 2
 ENTER 2 2
 LEAVE 2 2 1
 ENTER 3 0
 LEAVE 3 0 1
 ENTER 3 1
   ENTER 2 0
   LEAVE 2 0 1
   PART1 3 1 1
   ENTER 2 1
     ENTER 1 0
     LEAVE 1 0 1
     PART1 2 1 1
     ENTER 1 1
     LEAVE 1 1 1
     PART2 2 1 1
   LEAVE 2 1 2
   PART2 3 1 2
 LEAVE 3 1 3
 ENTER 3 2
   ENTER 2 1
     ENTER 1 0
     LEAVE 1 0 1
     PART1 2 1 1
     ENTER 1 1
     LEAVE 1 1 1
     PART2 2 1 1
   LEAVE 2 1 2
   PART1 3 2 2
   ENTER 2 2
   LEAVE 2 2 1
   PART2 3 2 1
 LEAVE 3 2 3
 ENTER 3 3
 LEAVE 3 3 1
 ENTER 4 0
 LEAVE 4 0 1
 ENTER 4 1
   ENTER 3 0
   LEAVE 3 0 1
   PART1 4 1 1
   ENTER 3 1
     ENTER 2 0
     LEAVE 2 0 1
     PART1 3 1 1
     ENTER 2 1
       ENTER 1 0
       LEAVE 1 0 1
       PART1 2 1 1
       ENTER 1 1
       LEAVE 1 1 1
       PART2 2 1 1
     LEAVE 2 1 2
     PART2 3 1 2
   LEAVE 3 1 3
   PART2 4 1 3
 LEAVE 4 1 4
 ENTER 4 2
   ENTER 3 1
     ENTER 2 0
     LEAVE 2 0 1
     PART1 3 1 1
     ENTER 2 1
       ENTER 1 0
       LEAVE 1 0 1
       PART1 2 1 1
       ENTER 1 1
       LEAVE 1 1 1
       PART2 2 1 1
     LEAVE 2 1 2
     PART2 3 1 2
   LEAVE 3 1 3
   PART1 4 2 3
   ENTER 3 2
     ENTER 2 1
       ENTER 1 0
       LEAVE 1 0 1
       PART1 2 1 1
       ENTER 1 1
       LEAVE 1 1 1
       PART2 2 1 1
     LEAVE 2 1 2
     PART1 3 2 2
     ENTER 2 2
     LEAVE 2 2 1
     PART2 3 2 1
   LEAVE 3 2 3
   PART2 4 2 3
 LEAVE 4 2 6
 ENTER 4 3
   ENTER 3 2
     ENTER 2 1
       ENTER 1 0
       LEAVE 1 0 1
       PART1 2 1 1
       ENTER 1 1
       LEAVE 1 1 1
       PART2 2 1 1
     LEAVE 2 1 2
     PART1 3 2 2
     ENTER 2 2
     LEAVE 2 2 1
     PART2 3 2 1
   LEAVE 3 2 3
   PART1 4 3 3
   ENTER 3 3
   LEAVE 3 3 1
   PART2 4 3 1
 LEAVE 4 3 4
 ENTER 4 4
 LEAVE 4 4 1
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Does that expand things enough for you?  If not, you might try breaking down the outer function into a series of calls, so you can see each in separate operation.

Answer (score 1):

With knowledge of the pascal triangle and more meaningful function and variable names, I'm sure you would have found the code self explanatory.

Here's the same code without the list comprehensions and using better variable names:

```
# PASCAL'S TRIANGLE:
# line 1            1
# line 2          1   1
# line 3        1   2   1
# line 4      1   3   3   1
# line 5    1   4   6   4   1
#
# Each line has one more value thant the previous one
# Each position on a line is the sum of the two numbers above it
# those  are the ones at index i-1 an i respectively,
# except for edges that are always 1

def valueAt(line,position): # func(x,y)
    if position == 0 or position == line:
        return 1
    return valueAt(line-1,position-1) + valueAt(line-1,position)

def pascalLine(N): # func2(N)
    triangle = []
    for lineNumber in range(N):
        line = []
        for position in range(lineNumber+1):
            value = valueAt(lineNumber,position)
            line.append(value)
        triangle.append(line)
    return triangle[N-1]
```

By the way, func2() is rather inefficient as it recreates the whole triangle to only use the last line.  Either that or func() is unnecessary because each new line in func2()'s triangle could have been built directly from the previous line.

If the idea was to create a recursive function to get a line of the pascal triangle based on the previous line, something much simpler would have been sufficient:

```
def pLine(N):
    if N==1: return [1]
    line = pLine(N-1)
    return list(map(sum,zip([0]+line,line+[0])))
```