# Complexity of scipy.special.binom?

Tags: scipy, binomial-coefficients

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31435571/6619250), there are two functions to calculate the binomial coefficient, also known as "N choose K". One of them is [`scipy.special.binom()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html).

Where is this function implemented? All I know is that it is a [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

Furthermore, what is the time complexity of `scipy.special.binom()`?

Comment: The source is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/orthogonal_eval.pxd#L68

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source can be found on Github in [orthogonal_eval.pxd](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/orthogonal_eval.pxd#L68).

In the integer case, the complexity is O(k).

```
kx = floor(k)
if k == kx and (fabs(n) > 1e-8 or n == 0):
    # Integer case: use multiplication formula for less rounding error
    # for cases where the result is an integer.
    #
    # This cannot be used for small nonzero n due to loss of
    # precision.

    nx = floor(n)
    if nx == n and kx > nx/2 and nx > 0:
        # Reduce kx by symmetry
        kx = nx - kx

    if kx >= 0 and kx < 20:
        num = 1.0
        den = 1.0
        for i in range(1, 1 + <int>kx):
            num *= i + n - kx
            den *= i
            if fabs(num) > 1e50:
                num /= den
                den = 1.0
        return num/den
```

Comment: thanks @jacques, the algorithm looks very cryptic to me - how does one tell that it's O(k)?

Comment: That's because of the for loop with k iterations. The rest of the code is more complex and one would need to check the helper functions to determine complexity.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Is it appropriate to claim that "In the integer case, the complexity is O(k)." if you don't know what the time complexity of the helper functions are?

Comment: @lightbox142 This answer dates back a bit but looking at it, I don't see any problem with it. Do you? Which helper function would be a problem?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin, from the code you mentioned, I'd just be concerned about fabs() function. What's the time complexity of that?

Comment: @lightbox142 `fabs` is the libc absolute value of floating-point number.

Comment: @lightbox142 `fabs` toggles 1 bit of a number.