# Binominal coefficient in python

Tags: python, loops, recursion, math, binomial-coefficients

so I was wondering how i could get around this problem where i have this code

```
    #defining a function that computes the factorial of an integer

def fac(b):
 if b==1:
    return 1
else:
    return b * fac(b-1)

#takes two integers and does the binomial coefficient operand

def combinations(n,k):
    result = (fac(n)) / (fac(k) * fac(n-k))
    return result

n=10
k=2

print(combinations(n,k))
```

and using it to (nCk) large numbers such as (1000,700) without using the

```
 sys.setreccursionlimit(x)
```

for example. can i somehow remove the lowest values in (6C3) so it just calculates (6x5x4)/(3x2x1) since 6! is 6x5x4x3x2x1 and 3! is 3x2x1. and the formula is n!/(k!x(n-k)!)

and therefore lowering the amounts of recursions happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Binomial Coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560726/python-binomial-coefficient)

Answer (score 2):

I feel you're kind of trying to reinvent the wheel here. This functionality already exists in the built-in `math` module, and it's quite efficient:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.comb(1000, 700)
542825004640614064815358503892902599588060075560435179852301016412253602009800031872232761420804306539976220810204913677796961128392686442868524741815732892024613137013599170443939815681313827516308854820419235457578544489551749630302863689773725905288736148678480
```

Comment: haha thats kind of the point, i dont want to use any inbuilt functions to solve this.

Comment: @LAXENOSUND keep in mind that Pythons inbuilt functions are written in C, which always makes them (much) faster than a pure Python solution.

Comment: @Damiaan oh, thanks thats good to know however i was just curiuos how this problem would be solved with just classic "functions" without having speed in mind.

Comment: Damiaan is exactly right, you can have a look at the [math implementation in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/mathmodule.c#L3390) and see how `C(n, k)` is computed, but don't expect to top that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cache` decorator ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), [nice video tutorial](https://youtu.be/DnKxKFXB4NQ))

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def fac(b):
    return b * fac(b-1) if b else 1

def combinations(n,k):
    M = max(n,k)
    for i in range(M):
        fac(i)
    return (fac(n)) // (fac(k) * fac(n-k))


n=1000
k=700
print(combinations(n,k))
```

Output

```
542825004640614064815358503892902599588060075560435179852301016412253602009800031872232761420804306539976220810204913677796961128392686442868524741815732892024613137013599170443939815681313827516308854820419235457578544489551749630302863689773725905288736148678480
```

Comment: This still results in `RecursionError`.

Comment: Add this two lines before the last one `M = max(n,k)`, `for i in range(M): fac(i)`. This plus the cache decorator will work (I modified my original answer)

Comment: Even so, the answer is not technically correct as it's lost precision due to the e+263

Comment: The division operator you should use in `combinations` is `//`, not the `/` that you're using now. `//` is exact integer division, and the theory guarantees that `(fac(k) * fac(n-k))` is a divisor of `fac(n)`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk is right! Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

### Factorial

Recursion is great in some languages, but absolutely sucks in python. Do not use recursion in python unless you have a very good reason to.

For your factorial function, I suggest using a simple loop:

```py
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for k in range(2,n+1):
        result *= k
    return result
```

Or you can use the `prod` function to compute the product of the `range` directly:

```py
from math import prod

def factorial(n):
    return prod(range(2, n+1))
```

Or you can use the existing `factorial` function directly:

```py
from math import factorial
```

### Binomial coefficient

Mathematicians like to "compress" the formula of the binomial coefficient as `(n choose k) = factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k))`, but this formula is inefficient for no good reason if used directly. Remember that all the factors in `factorial(n-k)` cancel out with the lower factors from `factorial(n)`. So, there is no need to compute the product of these factors at all.

Instead you can at least do this small optimisation:

```py
def binomial(n, k):
    a, b = (k, n-k) if k < n-k else (n-k, k)
    numerator = 1
    for i in range(b+1, n+1):
        numerator *= i
    return numerator / factorial(a)
```

Of course you can use the existing function `comb` directly:

```py
from math import comb
```